# Creating a C++ Project in miniCode

Tags: c++, ios

I am wondering if it is possible to create a C++ console project in miniCode. I am using an iPod Touch 5th Generation running iOS 7.0.2.

I have tried just changing the name of the source file to have a .cpp extension, but I get errors when using including files like iostream.

Here is the error I am getting when creating a simple hello world application:

/var/mobile/Library/miniCode/projects/Testing/src/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found

This probably means that creating a C++ project in miniCode is not possible, but I am wondering if there is anything I can do to make it work.

The Clang compiler supports C/C++ according to the LLVM+Clang by CoolStar package description on Cydia, so that is where I got the idea that I might be able to create a C++ project in miniCode.

Please excuse me if this is a simple or stupid question.

Comment: According to [Finke](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1846536/finke), who [says that he's a miniCode developer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24945196/456814): "*miniCode does support C/C++ projects and should work without a problem. Would you mind posting your code and telling me which SDK you're using?*"